# Disqus data URL from blogger post

Tags: blogger, disqus

I am trying to add a **blogger** post **URL** plus **#disqus_thread** into `data-disqus-url` of this span tag.

```
<span class="disqus-comment-count" data-disqus-url='???'/>
```

I tried something like this but nothing...

```
<span class="disqus-comment-count" data-disqus-url='data:post.url + &quot;#disqus_thread&quot;'/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't specified that it's the Blogger expression.

```
<span class="disqus-comment-count" expr:data-disqus-url="data:post.url + &quot;#disqus_thread&quot;"/>
```